# Does regulating a laser diode's power change the quality of the beam?

Tags: laser

In machine vision, you can use linear lasers as sheets of light to infer an object's 3D position or shape. (AFAIK it's just a laser beam stretched in one direction using optics.) Those are usually Class 3 or lower, and they're almost always based on laser diodes. Some of those lasers have a power regulation input. By changing the voltage on that pin, you can change the laser's output power.

What I'd like to understand is: if you change the output power, will all illuminated points on the object look the same, except for the linear scaling of their intensity? Or will some other qualities of the beam change as well?

I ask because the biggest annoyance with lasers when imaging small objects is the speckle. The beam you see with large magnification has grainy highs and lows on a scale way beyond the camera's dynamic range. Does the ratio of high and low points in the speckle stay the same, regardless of output power?

*Clarification:* Can it be said that more or less power, in principle, makes the speckle more severe? In terms of ratio of intensity at the peaks and valleys.

(Side note: I understand that the laser will *look* different in the image. It will seem wider if you increase power because the camera wasn't sensitive enough to sense the whole width before. But you'll get the same effect by changing the camera's exposure.)

Comment: For many lasers, changing the power can change the beam mode(s). What do you mean by 'quality' of the beam?

Comment: @jon I'm concerned about the speckle. Can changing the power level make it more or less grainy? Make the grains larger or smaller, more or less dense, larger or smaller ratio between peak and valley intensity?

Comment: If the mode(s) change or, more generally, the parameters of the Gaussian-like beam changes, then likely the speckle will change as well.

Comment: @jon Thanks for the info. I've added a clarification to the question now, hopefully it's a bit more specific. It's hard for me to expresses what interests me, but without making it too specific in a wrong way. Because I really don't understand lasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, modulating a laser’s power (by changing its driving current) can indeed effect its mode shape. But you’re asking about speckle, and more likely than not, speckle is coming from the optics *after* your laser rather than the laser itself. Speckle is just interference, which is linear. So merely scaling the intensity won’t help. What you need to do is minimize the opportunity for the beam to self-interfere. In particular: Are you using multi-mode fiber/waveguide? If so, you’ll get a lot of speckle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You've answered my question. As for your question, no extra optics other than what's already included in the device and I don't know what's inside. I just know that it's some non-spherical lens for stretching the dot into a line and that it compensates for the gaussian shape of the beam to make the line homogeneous length-wise. If you're curious, here's a datasheet of a typical laser we have used, for instance: https://z-laser.com/wp-content/uploads/_download/Datasheets/English/Z-LASER_Datasheet_ZM18.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a 2nd diode and that will reduce speckle by maybe 10% to 20%. But in general the coherence is intrinsic so power will not have an effect.  Also the optics can improve if you can increase aperture size, i.e. adding more broader angles to the illumination.